# Unknown Error after Intalled app

Tags: android, manifest

I get this picture after installing my app.
Its not posible to open it, aswell as the logo isnt in my home menu 
but the package is in app list in settings. 
Can anybody see whats wrong?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m444te4482wycfo/Screenshot_2013-11-19-19-14-21.png

**I have put my Manifest downunder**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zimzux.soundapprhk"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.zimzux.soundapprhk.Opstart"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zimzux.soundapprhk.OPSTART" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zimzux.soundapprhk.Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zimzux.soundapprhk.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

**My LogCat**

```
11-19 19:35:16.552: D/dalvikvm(6033): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41K, 5% free 6885K/7175K, paused 29ms
11-19 19:35:16.562: I/dalvikvm-heap(6033): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.158MB for 1440016-byte allocation
11-19 19:35:16.622: D/dalvikvm(6033): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 4% free 8289K/8583K, paused 2ms+13ms
11-19 19:35:16.722: D/ViewRootImpl(6033): pckname = com.zimzux.soundapprhk
11-19 19:35:16.752: D/libEGL(6033): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-19 19:35:16.762: I/dalvikvm(6033): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-19 19:35:16.772: I/dalvikvm(6033): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-19 19:35:16.782: D/libEGL(6033): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
11-19 19:35:16.782: D/libEGL(6033): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-19 19:35:16.802: D/OpenGLRenderer(6033): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: can you should the logcat messages?

Comment: In emulated, there is no problems.. its only when i try to install

Comment: logcat also works on devices, so please show that log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no icon in the list of available applications because you have no activity with the following `<intent-filter>`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Android uses this `<intent-filter>` to determine which activities can be launched by users.